# cakephp missing controller error

Tags: cakephp

I am very new to cakephp.

I have my project registration in the workspace. I have created an `IndexController`, which contains method `index()`.

When I run my project by using workspace/registration/ it displays the following error:

> Error:  WorkspaceController could not be found. Create the class WorkspaceController below in file: app/Controller/WorkspaceController.php.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

I think the error-message says it all;

Create the class WorkspaceController below in file:

```
app/Controller/WorkspaceController.php
```

Basically, using the default routes, urls use this schema:

```
http://mysite.com/mycontroller/myaction/param1/param2/param...
```

Will be routed to:

```
MycontrollerController::myaction($param1, $param2);
```

So with your url, CakePHP is trying to execute:

```
WorkspaceController::registration()
```

Which apparently doesn't exist

Comment: how can i change the default route? I want to exicute the IndexController first.

Comment: You can change your routes by specifying custom routes inside app/Config/routes.php. Here you can attach the 'homepage' to any controller/action and create custom routes. See this page for more information http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same message. Problem was that code was not wrapped inside `<?php ... ?>`. So basically code should look like:

```
<?php
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function index() {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use filename as `IndexController.php` instead of `index_controller.php` or anything else. I just don't know why, but it works fine in my case and your class name also should be `IndexController`

Comment: _"I just don't know why"_ — because [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) is configured that way.